# C++11 constructor inheritance not working

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

I tried the following code:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int a) {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::Base; // Inherit Base's constructors.
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived d(1);
}
```

This doesn't compile, and I get:

```
error C2664: 'Derived::Derived(const Derived &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Derived &'
```

(the relevant constructor can't be found and it tries to call the default copy constructor)

How can I fix the inheritance so that `Derived d(1);` will compile?

Comment: This might be compiler dependent, maybe your compiler is not configured to be in C++11 mode? Please include details about your compiler.

Comment: The code above compiles with g++ 4.8.2 and clang++ 3.5. What is your compiler?

Comment: Works with gcc4.9. I would guess this is a MSVC Bug.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 (v120)

Comment: definitely bug of compiler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx The constructor inheritance is not implemented in any of the existing Visual C++ compilers :(

However if we have the patience to wait some more time, according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx the upcoming release will have support for this.